# SSH Autologin not working

Tags: 16.04, bash, ssh

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 and a debian machine, both connected through a network. On my Ubuntu machine there is service running, which needs to reboot the debian computer when starting the service. The service is invoked by `sudo service debian_client start` and is doing a bunch of commands like `ssh root@192.168.0.1 reboot` on the debian machine. The problem is, I need to type in the password once for every ssh command, which is very annoying.

I tried then to go to `~/.ssh` on the Ubuntu machine and did

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id root@192.168.0.1
```

After that I logged in via `ssh root@192.168.0.1` which works without typing a password. But when invoking the ssh command through the service, I still have to type password. Does anybody know why and how to resolve this issue, I can't find help online for that specific problem?

Interesting part, I changed the script to `ssh -v root@192.168.0.1` and compared the output of the script with the output if I do that via bash. The difference is that the script always looks for keys in /root, like the output shows:

```
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

If I do it myself via bash, the output reads:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@ubuntucomputer
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

and I am logged in without any password typed. Can anybody help, why is my service looking for the key at /root/? Thank you very much.

Comment: What user does the service run as? what user did you go to `~/.ssh` and run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` as?

Comment: It seems that the key `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` is not the key copied with `ssh-copy-id root@192.168.0.1`. You could give `ssh-keygen`a path and filename. Then you might need to point the ssh connection in your service to your keyfile with `-i /path/to/keyfile`

Comment: Oh I forget to add that. I used ssh-copy-id with the -i option and copied the *.pub file from ~/.ssh/, hope that was right?

How can I find out about the user that starts the service? I thought thats myself or root. I did all ssh related commands from my user and checked the creation time of the key files in .ssh.

Comment: The **private** key file needs to be available to the service - either in the default location of the service owner, or passed to `ssh` explicitly with the `-i` option

Comment: Okay, the problem is, I should be able to use that script on several computers with different usernames, hence I can't define an exact path to the user's .ssh folder. The better solution would be to change the user, which executes the script, hows that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that:

- you generated ssh-key as user 'user' (ssh login working from bash/cli `debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@ubuntucomputer`)
- there is /home/user/.ssh folder with ssh keys.
- the servise is executed as 'service' user with home directory '/root'.

Possible quick way to make password less authentication working is:

`cd ~; sudo cp -R .ssh /root/`

Comment: Hi, I tried that, at first an error occured, @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/Key.pub' are too open.
I changed the permissions to -rw------- and tried again, but then the debain computer accepts the key, but asks for the passphrase. This however is not accepted and then again I am asked for the regular login passwort. The passphrase in this case is simply empty, does that matter?

Comment: I further tried to create a key file as root, hence it was then automatically created in /root/.ssh, and copied that to the debian server, but this doesn't help anyway.

Comment: SSH client is looking for files /root/.ssh/id_rsa, /root/.ssh/id_dsa,.... (look at your script debug output). Your public ssh key file is /root/.ssh/Key.pub.      Looks like default configuration is too modified. Then you should provide name of private key:
`ssh -i /root/.ssh/Key.private root@192.168.0.1`

Comment: And you should generate ssh key with option '-N': `ssh-keygen -N '' -t rsa`

Comment: Thanks @Ovidijus this was the correct hint, I need to pass the private key to the ssh command, not the public. Its working now!